# Program to list files of a process in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, process, filesystems, system

I need a program to list all the file that are accessed/opened by a process in Linux.
It should work like this,

o/p: The full path of the files that the process is accessing.

Don't want to use '**lsof**' utility or any other utility.

Is there anyway to achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the files which are accessible thru *opened* file descriptors by process of pid 1234, list the `/proc/1234/fd/` directory (most of the entries are symlinks). You'll also get additional details thru `/proc/1234/fdinfo/`

Try

```
ls -l /proc/self/fd/
```

to get an idea of what these files contain.

Programatically you could use [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) after [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html)  on these directories (and also [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html), at least for entries in `/proc/1234/fd/` ....). See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

<sup>Notice that `/proc/` is Linux specific. Some other Unixes have it (e.g. Solaris), with very different contents, properties, semantics.</sup>

If you care also about files which have been opened and closed in the past by some process, it is much more difficult. See also [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) and [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)...

To convert a file path to a "canonical" absolute fiile path, use [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

Comment: It works. Thanks i will write a prg using this idea.